# What are the ranges of bands that Android provide in Equalizer class?

Tags: android

By default, there are 5 bands that android provide in its Equalizer class.
I want to know what are the ranges of each band.

That is what is the starting & final range(Hz/KHz or any other unit) of each band.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it myself:

```
short minEQLevel = mEqualizer.getBandLevelRange()[0];
short maxEQLevel = mEqualizer.getBandLevelRange()[1];
```

Comment: It may be noted that even though the bands are only 5 in number,the presets are many in number depending on the Android Version used in the device.

Comment: @Sreekanth: I know by this way we can get the equalizer range. But is it possible to extend the equalize band from 5 to 10 or 20? Please reply me on this. thanks.